# Json format add a href link

Tags: php, json

I want to add "a href"  link in json format.
I am getting result like,

```
{"data": [[1,"HPP330","test330 hp","IN","Quiz 1",1,"Edit</a>"]]}
```

But i want to be result like this format:

```
<code>{"data": [[1,"HPP330","test330 hp","IN","Quiz 1",1,<a href ="">Edit</a>]]} </code>
```

Comment: what did you tried with php ?

Comment: Just read the json and add the href and again encode it into json

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
$str = '{"data": [[1,"HPP330","test330 hp","IN","Quiz 1",1]]}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
array_push($arr['data'][0], htmlentities("<a href='#'>Edit</a>"));
echo json_encode($arr); //{"data":[[1,"HPP330","test330 hp","IN","Quiz 1",1,"<a href='#'>Edit<\/a>"]]}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur feedback.
But i want to display a href after "IN" value.